# How to implement ssl in tomcat using CRT and PEM file (SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP)

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat7, tomcat8

I received ssl files from vendor - 2 crt files and one pem file. Can some one give steps how to implement ssl using these files in Tomcat 7 ?

I implemented below steps to store ssl files into keystore

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.jks -trustcacerts -file tomcat.pem 
keytool -import -alias comodo1 -keystore tomcat.jks -trustcacerts -file root.crt
keytool -import -alias comodo2 -keystore tomcat.jks -trustcacerts -file int.crt
```

configured below lines in Tomcat

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
SSLEnabled="true"
scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat.jks"
keystorePass="password"/>
```

also try to replace above protocol with **org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol** but still it didn't work on browser i got below error message. can some one help me on this.

```
An error occurred during a connection to XXXX:8443. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
```

Comment: I am sure there are plenty of guides online. Have you tried something before asking?

Comment: Yes Tsahi i tried i got the error - SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP even after multiple attempts

Comment: Now your question looks much better, that you describe what you tried. As it was before, it was a good candidate for deletion.

Answer (score 3):

Please run the below command and confirm if there is a **privatekeyEntry** in the keystore.

keytool -list -v -keystore < Keystore File Path>

[image]

If this entry is not available, then the keystore file can not be used for SSL Encryption.

Comment: yes privatekeyEntry is missing. I generated privatekey using keytool and now i can see that "privatekeyEntry" using above command. Now ssl application is accessible but its giving warning "connection is not secure" i think its referring self signed its not referring the CA certificate. did i missed any step ?

Comment: Yes, the error is because you are using a self signed certificate which is not trusted by the browser. Self signed certificates don't have a intermediate or root certificate who signed and approved the domain certificate. To overcome this, please purchase a public CA certificate.

Answer (score 0):

When installing the root certificate, you should use root.crt instead of tomcat.pem(I think this is your intermediate certificate).

I have followed the following steps to install and configure SSL on tomcat 8.

1. Generated keystore running command:

   **keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore**

   Generated csr file by running command:

   **keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file yourCSR.csr -keystore tomcat.keystore**

   Submitted CSR request on www.godaddy.com

Once my request is approved and goDaddy issued the certificates. I have followed the following steps(goDaddy sent this instruction along with the cert files).
Install the root certificate by running the following command:

**`keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file [name of the root certificate]`**

Install the intermediate certificate by running the following command:

**`keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file [name of the intermediate certificate]`** my intermediate cert ends with .pem

Install the issued certificate into the keystore by running the following command:

**`keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file [name of the certificate]`**

Finally I add/modified the following to  server.xml and restarted tomcat server.
**

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
   maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile=".mykeystore" keystorePass="xxxxxx"
   ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" />
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I need some clarity on tomcat.keystore file.

1.Before generating CSR key i see list of content inside tomcat.keystore it contains PrivateKeyEntry entry with Owner and Issuer details.( Owner and Issuer contains the information CN,OU ,L,ST etc same details which i entered while creation of tomcat.keystore. And now if i configure in tomcat till here will work as self signed certificate will show in browser Issuer details of mine. i agree this. 
2. After importing all certificates (of godaddy) into my tomcat.keystore and if i see the list i can see other entries like : trustedCertEntry with owner and issuer by godaddy. But in that list PrivateKeyEntry its showing Issuer as "XXX" which is entered while creation of tomcat.keystore. I can't see issuer name as a Godaddy.i am not sure where i am doing wrong.

Now after configure and start tomcat from browser the Issue name is showing "XXX" the same which i enter while creation of key.Even after importing all certificates of godaddy don't know why its not showing the Issue as godaddy in brower ?.

Comment: Now it make sense. While importing certificate i have to provide the same alias name which i given while creation of private key.